# Python:  Simulate re.findall in Pexpect module

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

Is it possible to simulate re.findall in the pexpect module?

I currently have a script that ssh's into a server using pexpect. I then have it send a command to the server which returns a bunch of lines in p.before (p being a pexpect spawn):

```
JUNK JUNK JUNK IP ADDRESS 10.0.0.1 JUNK JUNK
JUNK IP ADDRESS 10.0.0.3 JUNK JUNK JUNK
JUNK JUNK JUNK
IP ADDRESS 10.0.0.2 JUNK JUNK JUNK JUNK
```

Note: The ip addresses I used in the example are random ones I used just for this example. In the actual script, it can be any ip address. The information I am trying to find are the ip addresses.

Can pexpect do something like re.findall? Or do I have to do `re.findall(regex, p.before`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could hack what you're looking for by subclassing [searcher_re](http://pexpect.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3-1/classpexpect_1_1searcher__re.html) and using an `expect_loop` call with an instance of your subclass, which overrides the [search](http://pexpect.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3-1/classpexpect_1_1searcher__re_40f9887c976f3c7ed289b95105c3fe96.html#40f9887c976f3c7ed289b95105c3fe96) method.

In your override, before performing the main search for whatever you're using now, you can do a findall on the buffer for an IP-identifying RE, and accumulate those results in an instance variable of your own.  So, when `pexpect.expect_loop` returns, that variable on your instance will have the "extra info" you're looking for.

Seems like a little bit of trial and error would be needed to get it right, and I don't understand what advantages you expect (by this or any other hack to similar purposes) over the straightforward approach you've mentioned, i.e., just using `re.findall` directly, without messing with `pexpect`'s machinery -- care to explain...?